# Inheritance and Pointers of Base Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, ambiguity

I was going through this [Book](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.linux.doc/language_ref/cplr139.html) and I can't wrap my head around this:

if `B::f(int)` hides `A::f()`, why does `pa1->f();` not give an error?

Doesn't name hiding mean that, the function `f()` doesn't exist in `class B`? And if `pa1` points to an object of `class B` then `pa1->f();` should result in an error just as `b.f()` does!

Please explain this, as I can't understand it through the book! 
Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
   virtual void f() { cout << "Class A" << endl; }
};

struct B: A {
   void f(int) { cout << "Class B" << endl; }
};

struct C: B {
   void f() { cout << "Class C" << endl; }
};

int main() {
   B b; C c;
   A* pa1 = &b;
   A* pa2 = &c;
//   b.f();
   pa1->f();
   pa2->f();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if `B::f(int)` hides `A::f()`, why does `pa1->f();` not give an error?

Because `pa1` points to `A`, and `A` has a member called `f` which can be called like that. In this context, any other class (including `B`) is irrelevant.

> Doesn't name hiding mean that, the function `f()` doesn't exist in class `B`?

No. It means that, in the context of `B`, the only function called `f` that can be found by unqualified lookup is `B::f`. It doesn't remove `f` from any other context, or prevent it from being found by *qualified* lookup such as `b.A::f()`.

> And if `pa1` points to an object of class `B` then `pa1->f();` should result in an error just as `b.f()` does!

The *dynamic* type is `B`, so that's the type used (at run time) to call *virtual* functions. Non-virtual functions are selected by the compiler according to the *static* type, which is `A`. In general, the compiler doesn't know the dynamic type; all it knows is that the pointer points to an `A` or some unknown derived class.

Answer (score 2):

It would be an error if you tried to call `f()` from scope of `B`. But, you're calling it through a pointer to base class. The name lookup and overload resolution is done based on the static type of the object, `A*` in this case. From there, `f()` is visible.

Answer (score 1):

The call pa1->f(); is first routed to object of type A, since pa1 is a pointer to that type. The virtual keyword would re-route the call to type B if there was a function that matches the exact(!!) signature of the call. Since there is no such function in type B, the type A function is executed.

What I mean is that in this case the functions do not "hide" each other because the signature differs. [f(void) vs. f(int)]

EDIT:
To be more clear. f(int) and f(void) are two completely different functions. As different as f(void) to g(int) would be.